# Htaccess, letters, numbers and spaces

Tags: .htaccess

I'm haivng trouble setting up a htaccess rule to follow this convention

www.siteurl.com/item/[NUMBERS][SPACE][LETTERS]/
eg www.siteurl.com/item/82 chocolate

which rewrites to

www.siteurl.com/index.php?page=home&i=$1

EDIT 11-05-16 18:00

```
RewriteRule ^item/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$            index.php?page=home&i=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `\s` char inside regex `character-class` to allow space(s) in the uri

```
RewriteRule ^item/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$          index.php?page=home&i=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, i then get a The requested URL item/82 chocolate was not found on this server.